Legend Cropped on First Export Using PyQGIS - Why Does It Render Correctly on the Second Export?
My function below creates a map in my processing toolbox. I am having a problem with the legend.
def create_geology_overview_map(project, vlyr_ezgStats, ezg_qml, vlyr_geol, geologische_layer_qml,
                                    geologische_karte_qpt, imgDir):
  """
  Creates a geological overview map in QGIS and exports it as a PNG image.
  """
  # Calculate the bounding box of the buffered EZG statistics layer
  bbox, vlyr_buffer = calculate_bounding_box(vlyr_ezgStats)

  # Store the names of the currently visible layers/groups
  root = project.layerTreeRoot()
  checked_groups = [layer.name() for layer in root.children() if layer.isVisible()]

  # Uncheck all layers/groups
  for group in checked_groups:
    if root.findGroup(group):
      root.findGroup(group).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

  # Add and style the EZG stats layer
  root.insertLayer(0, vlyr_ezgStats)
  vlyr_ezgStats.loadNamedStyle(ezg_qml)
  vlyr_ezgStats.triggerRepaint()

  # Add and style the geology layer
  root.insertLayer(1, vlyr_geol)
  vlyr_geol.loadNamedStyle(geologische_layer_qml)
  vlyr_geol.triggerRepaint()

  # Read the layout template
  composition = QgsPrintLayout(project)

  templateFile = open(geologische_karte_qpt, 'r')
  templateContent = templateFile.read()
  templateFile.close()

  document = QDomDocument()
  document.setContent(templateContent)

  # Load layout from template and add to Layout Manager
  composition.loadFromTemplate(document, QgsReadWriteContext())
  project.layoutManager().addLayout(composition)
  layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName("wlk_kennzahlen_geo")

  # Access and update the legend
  layoutItemLegend = layout.itemById('Legend1')
  # Deactivate auto refresh of the legend
  layoutItemLegend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)

  model = layoutItemLegend.model()
  tree_legend = model.rootGroup()

  QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(tree_legend.children()[0], QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
  QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(tree_legend.children()[1], QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
  layoutItemLegend.updateLegend()
  layout.refresh()

  # Remove the EZG stats layer from the legend
  layoutItemLegend.model().rootGroup().removeLayer(vlyr_ezgStats)
  layoutItemLegend.adjustBoxSize()
  layoutItemLegend.updateLegend()
  layout.refresh()

  # Adjust the map frame extent and scale
  mapFrame = layout.itemById("Map1")
  mapFrame.zoomToExtent(bbox[0])
  referencemap = layout.referenceMap()
  mapFrame.setScale(referencemap.scale() + 40000)
  layout.refresh()

  # Creates a QgsLayoutExporter object
  exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
  image_export_settings_geo = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
  image_export_settings_geo.dpi = 300
  image_export_settings_geo.cropToContents = False
  # image_export_settings.imageSize = QSize(2000, 2000)

  ### Exports an image of the layout object -1
  exporter.exportToImage(os.path.join(imgDir, 'geologische_karte.png'), image_export_settings_geo)

  ### Exports an image of the layout object -2
  exporter.exportToImage(os.path.join(imgDir, 'geologische_karte2.png'), image_export_settings_geo)


  # Restore visibility of previously visible layers/groups
  for group in checked_groups:
    if root.findGroup(group):
      root.findGroup(group).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)


  # Remove the layout from the manager
  project.layoutManager().removeLayout(layout)

  # Remove the temporary layers from the TOC
  root.removeLayer(vlyr_ezgStats)
  root.removeLayer(vlyr_geol)

When I call the function as it is above, it creates a map, but the legend is cropped, as shown in the image.

Strangely, after the second call of exporter, the legend appears correctly. What am I missing? Why is it cropped after the first call?

